# wpf Datagrid:Combobox Integration in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with 2 columns item ,Purchase Rate respectively.The Item column is a DatagridCombobox column ,Now I want to add all Items to that combobox from my Item database table .How do I bind It ,also How do I represent the Item Collection in my object ?

MY Xaml is :

```
 <my:DataGrid Name="dgReceiveInventory" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   SelectionUnit="Cell"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >
      <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--3-Product Column-->
                    <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="Product Name" Width="200" Binding="{Binding ProductName}" IsReadOnly="True"> <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn
       <!--7-Purchase Rate Column-->
                    <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Purchase Rate" ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBlockContentRightAlign}" Width="100" Binding="{Binding PurchaseRate}" IsReadOnly="True"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
      </my:DataGrid.Columns>
 </my:DataGrid>
```

My class is :

```
 class clsItems : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
     private string _ProductName;
     private decimal _PurchaseRate;

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return _ProductName; }
        set
        {
            _ProductName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
        }
    }

    public decimal PurchaseRate 
    {
        get { return _PurchaseRate; }
        set
        {
            _PurchaseRate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PurchaseRate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one question? is it your requirement is just to display the purchase rate of selected item or you have to do more.? If so don't use data grid, just have comboBox and textBox, bind a List to ComboBox and based on the selection update the purachase rate in the textbox from the view model.


Change the type of ProductName to List<string> create a list of all the product names

Comment: My datagrid also has another columns like amount,discount,total etc

Comment: At time if your displaying the details of only one item then have only combo box and the number of textboxes to display to details of the selected item. This will make you easier

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to bindto an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

First you'd add all the items from your database to the `ObservableCollection<clsItem>` Property in your ViewModel, or Code behind (don't know if you are using MVVM, but I strongly recommend it). Then you'd DataBind to your ViewModel or code behind.
After that you set the `ItemsSource` Property to the `ObservableCollection`.

Here is a very simple example code (not in MVVM):

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //This is the Collection you will DataBind your ComboBox to
    public ObservableCollection<clsItems> ItemsCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<clsItems>
        {
            new clsItems()
            {
                ProductName = "Product 1",
                PurchaseRate = 10
            },
            new clsItems()
            {
                ProductName = "Product 2",
                PurchaseRate = 20
            }
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The XAML File:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsCollection}"
                  SelectionUnit="Cell"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!--3-Product Column-->
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Product Name"
                                         Width="200"
                                         IsReadOnly="True"
                                         Binding="{Binding ProductName}">
                    <!--7-Purchase Rate Column-->
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Purchase Rate"
                                    Width="100"
                                    Binding="{Binding PurchaseRate}"
                                    IsReadOnly="True">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

What do we do here?
First we set the `DataContext` of the Window to itself (in MVVM you'd bind to the ViewModel instead). With that we can access the public properties of the window.
Second we set the `ItemsSource` Property of the ComboBox to the ObservableCollection property we have defined in the CodeBehind file.
Third we set the DisplayMember Path to the `ProductName` property. If we wouldn't do that the ComboboBox would just display WPFApplication1.clsItems, not the name of the Item in the collection.
Lastly we set the `SelectedIndex` to zero so the ComboBox will display an item. Of course you could also databind the SeletedIndex (or better SelectedItem) to a Property in the code behind file and further process the data the user selects

With that you only have to change the underlying collection and it will automatically reflect in the ComboBox in the view.

I hope this helps. You can find more on databinding [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

P.S. I'd rename clsItems just to Items, it should be clear that Items is a class.

Comment: But I am using combobox as datagridCombobox column my entire datagrid is bind to a collection of objects .Actually I want to load a column with some collection that is from my database table

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Do you have a ComboBox in a Datagrid? If yo, it does not matter as the binding is still the same. Or do you have a Datagrid inside your ComboBox?

Comment: Ok, so I took your code and threw it into my IDE. I changed it and now it displays the name and the Purchase Rate in a datagrid. I think your error was to use a ComboBoxColumn. I hope this is how you want to do it. If not, leave a comment how you want to do it and I'll help you.